# Java: Why is the result 5 and not 10?

Tags: java, oop

let a A.java file be :

```
    class B {static int i; }

    class A {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            B a=new B();
            B b=new B(); 
            a.i=10;
            b.i=5; 

            System.out.println(a.i);
        }
    }
```

Why is the result 5 and not 10 ?

Thanks.

Comment: I suggest you look up the definition of the word `static` as it pertains to Java.

Comment: Because Java allows a very confusing syntax for `static` member access. If you change all the `a.i`s to `B.i` (which is the more sensible way to access a `static` member) then everything becomes a lot clearer.

Comment: @Adamski: I see no reason to think this is homework. It would be pretty bizarre homework. Is the OP learning Java, and a novice? Yes, presumably so. Does that make this code homework? Nope.

Comment: Read the warning message. That should answer the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because your variable is static. That means it's related to the *type*, not to any particular *instance* of the type. Your code is equivalent to:

```
// These are actually ignored as far as the subsequent lines are concerned.
// The constructor will still be executed, but nothing is going to read the
// values of variables "a" and "b".
B a = new B();
B b = new B();

// Note this is the *type name*.
B.i = 10;
B.i = 5; 
System.out.println(B.i);
```

IMO it was a design mistake to allow access to static members via expressions like this - and in some IDEs (e.g. Eclipse) it can end up giving a warning or even an error if you so wish.

Comment: Quick question: Does your comment "These are actually ignored" apply only to the fact that `a.i` is really just `B.i`, or are you saying that the constructor for `B` has no visible side-effects, and the variables are never *actually* used, and so the compiler will not generate byte-code for those statements? I'm assuming it's the former, but figured I'd ask anyway :)

Answer (score 3):

It's because you declared `i` to be static. <strike>Therefore, all instances of `B` share the same value and memory location.</strike> (Therefore, there `B` is associated with the type rather than the instance.)

So when you do this:

```
a.i=10;
b.i=5;
```

You are actually writing to the value variable. Hence why `5` gets printed out instead of `10`.

Comment: I think it's best not to say "all instances" - the instances are *irrelevant*, and in particular it would work the same way if there were *no* instances. It's better (IMO) to talk about the variable being associated with the type, rather than instances of the type.

Comment: But your edited version still talks about "all instances". Imagine if there had been no constructor calls at all - if `a` and `b` were null. The code would work the same way - but talking about "all instances" would sound very odd, when there weren't any.

Answer (score 2):

Because i is a static variable, it belong to the class, not to the objects of that class.

It's like a 'global' variable....study the 'static' keyword in java.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The value of a static member of a class is shared across all instances of a class.

Thus, when you set b.i=5, it also sets a.i to 5.

Note, that b.i and a.i actually *share* the same memory. So it's really "B.i" not a.i or b.i.

Comment: See my comment to Mysticial. There *is* no `a.i` or `b.i` really - it's just `B.i`.

Comment: You're still talking about it being "shared across all instances". Imagine we hadn't created *any* instances. How should your answer be read then?

Answer (score 0):

Ill would say from this example that static says that whatever you are going to do with that int can only have one asigned value. So a.i and b.i just are different points of entry to the static int.